# Python - Getting string from list inside dict

Tags: python

I know this is something purely simple, but I can't wrap my head around it. I want to access the song "Sunrise" in the following dict/list. What's the proper way to do this with Python?

```
{"Player": 
    {"Playlist": 
        [
            {"Song" : "Foo", "Album" : "Bar"}, 
            {"Song" : "Sunrise", "Album", : "Random"}
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to *only* access the song sunrise? Keep in mind the key is "Song" and "Sunrise" is the value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
d = {"Player": 
    {"Playlist": 
        [
            {"Song" : "Foo", "Album" : "Bar"}, 
            {"Song" : "Sunrise", "Album", "Random"}
        ]
    }
}

for song in d['Player']['PlayList']:
    print song
```

Prints:

```
{'Album': 'Bar', 'Song': 'Food'}
{'Album': 'Random', 'Song': 'Sunrise'}
```

To access an element of a list in a dictionary, in this instance the value `Sunrise` inside of `Song`:

```
for song in d['Player']['Playlist']:
    if song['Song'] is 'Sunrise':
        #do thing with song here
        print song
```

prints:

```
{'Album': 'Random', 'Song': 'Sunrise'}
```

In Python, a Dictionary can contain lots of different types of values for a given key.  Breaking down your dictionary, this is what everything actually is:

```
{"Player":  
    {"Playlist": 
        [
            {"Song" : "Foo", "Album" : "Bar"}, 
            {"Song" : "Sunrise", "Album", "Random"}
        ]
    }
}
```

> `d['Player']:`

**Result**: `{'Playlist': [{'Album': 'Bar', 'Song': 'Food'}, {'Album': 'Random', 'Song': 'Sunrise'}]}`

The Key is a string, the value is a dictionary of playlists.

---

> `d['Player']['Playlist']:`

**Result**: `{'Playlist': [{'Album': 'Bar', 'Song': 'Food'}, {'Album': 'Random', 'Song': 'Sunrise'}]}`

the key is `Playlist`, the value is a `list` of `dict`ionaries.

---

> `d['Player']['Playlist'][0]`

**Result**: `{'Album': 'Bar', 'Song': 'Food'}`

This is a list accessor, it access the first element in the list (in this case, the `dict` that holds the `Album` and the `Song`)

---

> `d['Player']['Playlist'][0]['Album']:`

**Result**: 'Bar'

Accesses the value of the dictionary with the key `Album` inside the first element of the list inside the playlist.

---

Or, to spell it out if you're a perl guy, you have a dictionary of `Player`s that has a dictionary of `Playlists` with a list of dictionaries of songs (song data) inside of it.

Comment: Wow, brilliant answer! Thanks for taking the time to write that out!

Answer (score 1):

If `d` is your dictionary, then

```
 d['Player']['Playlist'][1]['Song']
```